# Checkbox Binding Information in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls

I have a code snippet as below

```
<CheckBox Name="cb" Margin="1,2,1,0"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsManager}" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

Consider I don't know which property is bind to IsChecked property. I want to get programattically know the binding information of IsChecked property. How can do  I that?

Comment: Do you mean in C#, you want to get the binding for the IsChecked property of CheckBox cb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(cb, CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
```

Or you can get the actual expression generated for that particular instance of the binding:

```
var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(cb, CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
```

Comment: That's great and very fast and userful
I finally got like this
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(a, CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
                    string property = binding.Path.Path.ToString();